# Есть ли речевые ошибки в четверостишии?

Tags: грамотная-речь

И будем же всё так тверды
В мечтах сокровенных и целях,
Чтоб даже капризы судьбы
Не сбили нас в этих стремленьях.

Вопрос: "капризы не сбили в стремленьях" - может ли что-то сбить в стремлении? Или получается, что будто капризы находятся в стремленьях, а не человек? И ещё маленький вопрос: можно ли быть твёрдым в мечтах и целях? Понятно же, что имеется в виду твёрдым в их достижении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Речевых ошибок нет, как, впрочем, и  поэтических достоинств.

**1) Капризы судьбы могут помешать человеку, остановить (сбить) в его стремлениях.**

Пример: Её уже ничто не могло остановить в стремлении сохранить свою жизнь. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 2 (1960)]

**2) В мечтах и целях можно быть твердым (=упорным).** Твердым может быть человек в своих стремлениях и намерениях, также твердыми могут быть сами намерения.

Из словаря: ТВЕРДЫЙ 4. **Такой, который устоит**, не отступит перед чем-л., останется верным своим убеждениям, целям, намерениям; стойкий, непоколебимый (о человеке). Быть твёрдым по своим убеждениям. **Остаться твёрдым в своём решении.** 5. **Такой, от которого не отступают**, которому не изменяют; непоколебимый, нерушимый. Т-ое решение. Т-ое намерение.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу только опечатку: здесь должно быть не "**ё**" а "**е**" (если это призыв ко всем, а не коллективное обещание твёрдости; иначе порядок слов должен быть таким: *"... всё так же тверды"*). Остальное допустимо: там не "что-то" сбить, а "кого" - нас. Желательно было бы уточнение "сбить нас с чего? (напр. с мыслей о намеченной цели и т. п.)" - этого нет, но такое упрощение извинительно в интересах сохранения ритма и рифмы. Капризы судьбы (т. е. непредвиденные события) вполне могли бы "сбить нас" (с пути или с мыслей - пока мы стремимся к этой самой твёрдости). "Твёрдым в мечтах и целях" быть можно: это означает готовность придерживаться намеченных целей и не отказываться от давней мечты под действием текущих обстоятельств. Общая логическая цепь такая: *"Мы должны (или стремимся) быть твёрдыми в мечтах и целях, и в этих стремлениях к твёрдости (в одном и другом) нас не должны сбить (в наших намерениях) даже капризы судьбы"*. При всех идейных недостатках и банальностях стишка явных речевых ошибок не видно.