# В четверостишье или в четверостишьи?

Tags: орфография, морфология, окончания

В данном источнике говорится, что верны обе формы: [четверостишье | morfologija.ru](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Вопрос: как можно проверить эту информацию и много ли у нас таких слов, где допускаются подобные вариативные окончания?

Кажется, возможны два варианта: в молчанье (нейтр.) и в молчаньи (поэт.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно: *в четверостишии*. Написание *четверостишье* не фиксируется авторитетными источниками, однако [встречается](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F7%E5%F2%E2%E5%F0%EE%F1%F2%E8%F8%FC%E5&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) в текстах из Корпуса. Можно сделать вывод, что оно возможно, но при этом четко разграничивать сферу его употребления: разговорная или поэтическая речь.

Правила таковы:

Слова среднего рода на *-ие* имеют в предложном падеже, в отступление от общего правила, окончание *-и*, а не *-е*: *в сопровождении, в молчании, в подразделении*. Слова среднего рода на 

*-ье* имеют в предложном падеже окончание *-е: в ущелье, о варенье*.
У большого количества слов есть вариантные формы на *-ие* и на *-ье*, например: *проклятие - проклятье, спасение - спасенье, возвращение - возвращенье, признание - признанье, **молчание - молчанье*** и т. п. При этом формы на *-ие* часто являются общеупотребительными и стилистически нейтральными, а формы на *-ье* характерны для разговорной и поэтической речи (хотя может быть наоборот, ср. *счастье* - общеупотребительный вариант, *счастие* - устаревший, встречающийся в поэтических текстах). При наличии таких вариантов на *-ие* и *-ье* указанные падежные формы имеют разные окончания *-и* и *-е*, например: *об умении - об уменье, в молчании - в молчанье*.
Однако в художественной, особенно поэтической, речи допускается написание форм предложного падежа существительных среднего рода на *-ье* (обычно при предлоге *в*) с окончанием *-и*, например: *В молчаньи шел один ты с мыслию великой* (Пушкин). Ошибкой здесь это не является.
См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006 (и более поздние издания).

См. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B8).

Comment: Меня, собственно говоря, заинтересовало правильное написание вопроса на сайте: "Есть ли речевые ошибки в четверостишьи?"   Здесь же не художественная и не поэтическая речь,  поэтому надо бы использовать нейтральную форму -  "в четверостишье". Или это не обязательно, ведь никто не стал исправлять окончание?

Comment: @Sibylla я уже неоднократно критиковал все эти онлайн-сайты по морфемному составу слов или морфологическому разбору: они могут содержать совсем неправильную информацию и ни за что не отвечают; тем более на них нельзя сослаться как на надежный источник. Вероятно, эта ситуация — лишнее подтверждение.

Comment: Нейтральная форма — и это точно! — *четверостиш**ие***. *Четверостиш**ья*** в словарях нет.

Comment: А почему Вы тогда не отредактировали название? Как-то оно смотрится не лучшим образом.

Comment: @Sibylla простите, а о каком названии идет речь? Я, кажется, что-то упустил.

Comment: Совсем недавно обсуждался вопрос  http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429804/Есть-ли-речевые-ошибки-в-четверостишьи

Comment: @Sibylla а, понял. К сожалению, часто я быстрым взглядом смотрю лишь на технические элементы: метки, неправильное оформление и т. п., и т. д. Спасибо за замечание! Вы всегда можете исправить ошибку, если заметили ее где-либо на сайте.

Answer (score 3):

Четверостишие , в четверостишии - общеупотребительный и стилистически нейтральный вариант.

Четверостишье, в четверостишье - характерно для разговорной и поэтической речи.

Большинство подобных слов имеют в таких вариантах формы на -ие и -ье, например: учение, знание, сознание, молчание и т. п. (правда, может быть наоборот, например, счастье - общеупотребительный вариант, счастие - устаревший вариант, встречающийся в поэзии).

В художественной, особенно поэтической, речи допускается написание форм предл. п. существительных сред. рода на -ье (обычно при предлоге в ) с окончанием -и, например: В молчаньи шел один ты с мыслию великой (П.) ; Подвиг есть и в сраженьи, / Подвиг есть и в борьбе. / Высший подвиг – в терпеньи, / В любви и мольбе (Хом.) ; И снег соперничал в усердьи / С сумерничающею смертью (Б. Паст.) ; «В очарованьи» (название стихотворения И. Северянина) ; Птицы кричат в поднебесьи, / Сердце стучит в подреберьи (В. Долина) .

Под ударением окончание предл. п. -и отмечается только у одного слова на -ье: забытьё – в забытьи. Это наводит на мысль, что такое словоизменение было, возможно, в старославянском языке, ведь все старославянизмы используются в поэзии как высокие слова.

Насчёт проверки этой информации сложнее, если только всё этот же сайт Морфология.ру:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1pRK.png]